# vba select only cells with value in range

Tags: excel, vba

I want to select only cells that contains data in specific range (C7:I15). Code below can do that only for column "G". How to change code for my range?

```
Sub Testa()
Dim LR As Long, cell As Range, rng As Range
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    LR = .Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cell In .Range("G2:G" & LR)
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = cell
            Else
                Set rng = Union(rng, cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    rng.Select
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Are there formulas in the respective range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generic function to which you pass the range that should be checked - and which returns a range with the non-empty cells (see update below for function using SpecialCells instead of iteration)

```vb
Public Function rgCellsWithContent(rgToCheck As Range) As Range
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In rgToCheck
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        If rgCellsWithContent Is Nothing Then
            Set rgCellsWithContent = cell
        Else
            Set rgCellsWithContent = Union(rgCellsWithContent, cell)
        End If
    End If
Next cell

End Function
```

You can use this sub like this:

```vb
Sub Testa()

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'select cells in range C7:I15
    rgCellsWithContent(.Range("C7:I15")).Select

    'select cells in column G
    Dim LR As Long
    LR = .Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    rgCellsWithContent(.Range("G2:G" & LR)).Select
    
    'you can even combine both
    Dim rgNew As Range
    Set rgNew = rgCellsWithContent(.Range("C7:I15"))
    Set rgNew = Union(rgNew, rgCellsWithContent(.Range("G2:G" & LR)))
    
    rgNew.Select
End With

End Sub
```

**UPDATE**:

This function uses the SpecialCells command.

You can make a difference to return values only or to return values and formulas.

```vb
Public Function rgCellsWithContent(rgToCheck As Range, _
    Optional fValuesAndFormulas As Boolean = True) As Range
    
Dim cell As Range

On Error Resume Next 'in case there are no cells

With rgToCheck
    Set rgCellsWithContent = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    
    If fValuesAndFormulas Then
        Set rgCellsWithContent = Union(rgCellsWithContent, .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas))
    End If
End With

On Error GoTo 0
        
End Function
```

Comment: `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)` may also return an empty string and in such  case they must be excluded...

Answer (score 1):

If no formulas in the range where selection should be done, you can use the next compact code, not needing any iteration:

```
    Dim rng As Range
    On Error Resume Next 'for the case of no any empty cell
     Set rng = Range("C7:I15").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.Select
```

The next version is able to deal with formulas, too:

```
    Dim rng As Range, rngSel As Range, arrFormula
    Set rng = Range("C7:I15")
    With rng
        arrFormula = .Formula
        .Value = .Value
        On Error Resume Next
         Set rngSel = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Formula = arrFormula
    End With
    If Not rngSel Is Nothing Then rngSel.Select
```